# the following message appear "(-bash: file_name : Prmission denied)" when i try to do backup of the SVN

Tags: linux, svn, command-line-interface, ubuntu-10.04

Please if you can help me  when I made the backup in the "root" /home  the size of the root space is not big enough so I try to make the backup on another place "/backup" but the following message appears : (`-bash: file_name : Prmission denied`)

Comment: does `svnadmin dump /path/to/repo > /dev/null` and `head /dev/urandom > /path/to/dumpfile` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote you use sudo. The command

```
# sudo svnadmin dump myrepos > dumpfile
```

will run ``svnadmin dump myrepos`with the rights of root. The`> dumpfile` part will **not** have the rights of root.

You could write a script, put the command in it and *sudo* the whole script or construct a one-liner like

```
# sudo svnadmin dump myrepos | sudo tee dumpfile > /dev/null
```

or

```
# sudo sh -c 'svnadmin dump myrepos > dumpfile'
```

or

```
# svnadmin dump myrepos | sudo tee dumpfile > /dev/null
```

if you are allowed to read `myrepos` with user-rights

Answer (score 0):

You may not have permission to (a) read files in /home, especially if its a shared host, or (b) write to /backup.  If you run it as root (using either su or sudo), you should be able to run the command.

EDIT: When you run sudo, what you'll want to do is `sudo sh -c 'svnadmin dump myrepos > dumpfile'`; that way, you're running the entire command--redirection and all--as root.

Comment: i used sudo but the same message appear !!! i don't konow why ... in other word the following command don't work any where elsa home "svnadmin dump myrepos > dumpfile" ... any other plase give me "NO Prmission"

Comment: How did you run that command?  If you did `sudo svnadmin dump myrepos > dumpfile`, you are only assuming superuser access for the svnadmin aspect.  What you'll want to do is `sudo sh -c 'svnadmin dump myrepos > dumpfile'`; that way, you're running the entire command--redirection and all--as root.